# How to make 'Reactjs Modal' appearing in screen flying from right to centre

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a react Modal. When it is invoked, it opens up in the center of browser window. I want some changes in the Modal opening style. 
When Modal is invoked, it should come flying from right to center. I dont know about the property/attribute which can enable such appearance. can someone please help.
This is my current styling:

```
customStyles = {
overlay: {
  position: 'fixed',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.75)'
},
content: {
  display: 'relative',
  position: 'absolute',
  textAlign: 'Center',
  top: '20%',
  left: '20%',
  right: '20%',
  bottom: '4%',
  border: '6px solid #ccc',
  background: '#fff',
  overflow: 'auto',
  WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch',
  borderRadius: '4px',
  outline: 'none',
  padding: '20px',
  paddingLeft: '40px'
}};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this class name

example:

```
.modal-center{
      animation: left-to-center linear 1s;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -webkit-animation: left-to-center linear 1s;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -moz-animation: left-to-center linear 1s;
      -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -o-animation: left-to-center linear 1s;
      -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -ms-animation: left-to-center linear 1s;
      -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }

    @keyframes left-to-center{
      0% {
        transform:  translate(250px,0px)  ;
      }
      100% {
        transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
      }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes left-to-center{
      0% {
        -moz-transform:  translate(250px,0px)  ;
      }
      100% {
        -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes left-to-center {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(250px,0px)  ;
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
      }
    }

    @-o-keyframes left-to-center {
      0% {
        -o-transform:  translate(250px,0px)  ;
      }
      100% {
        -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
      }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes left-to-center {
      0% {
        -ms-transform:  translate(250px,0px)  ;
      }
      100% {
        -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px)  ;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sugumar K. It is helpful!
But I am more interested in making the modal coming 'flying' from 'right to center', not 'sliding'. The code you have given makes the modal coming 'sliding' from right to center. Is there a way it can be done. I am not having the specific word to point to that behavior, but to elaborate -
1. It should appear flying from right to center
2. it should not be fully opened since the beginning of fly, rather should get opened slowly on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
```

to your `Content` class.

Another alternative is to use a different react modal component such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-slider